# Can't get the current date to display in the textbox

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function displayDate() {

      var date = new Date();
      const monthArray = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
      const dayArray = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];

      var Date = date.getDate();
      var month = monthArray[date.getMonth()];
      var year = date.getFullYear();
      var day = dayArray[date.getDay()];
      var hours = date.getHours() % 12;
      var minutes = date.getMinutes();
      var amPm = "AM";

      if (hours < 10) {
        hours = "0" + hours;
      }

      if (date.getHours() > 12) {
        amPm = "PM";
      }
      var str = Date + " " + month + " " + year + " " + day + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + amPm;
      document.getElementById("date1").value = str;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  Current date: <input id="date1" type="text" size="30" onload="displayDate()">

</body>

</html>
```

Hi guys, I am trying to display the current date in the textbox. However, I can't seem to get it to work. When the program ran, the textbox did not display anything. I tried using a console.log function to print the output in the console but it didn't seem to work as well. Kindly advise for a solution, thank you.

Comment: Move `onload="displayDate()"` to the `<body>` tag.

Comment: thanks bro this helped (:

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `onload()` and simply call your function when the window loads.

Something like that:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    displayDate();
});
```

However, your code has a problem you should be aware of. You cannot name a variable with the name "Date" because this causes conflict with Global function Date(). Instead, rename your variable somehow else. I will include my code to show you what I mean.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
    
</head>

<body>

    Current date: <input id="date1" type="text" size="30">

</body>

<script>
    function displayDate() {

        console.log("hey!");

        let date = new Date();
        const monthArray = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
        const dayArray = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];

        var theDate = date.getDate();
        var month = monthArray[date.getMonth()];
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        var day = dayArray[date.getDay()];
        var hours = date.getHours() % 12;
        var minutes = date.getMinutes();
        var amPm = "AM";

        if (hours < 10) {
            hours = "0" + hours;
        }

        if (date.getHours() > 12) {
            amPm = "PM";
        }
        var str = theDate + " " + month + " " + year + " " + day + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + amPm;
        document.getElementById("date1").value = str;
    }


    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        displayDate();
    });
</script>

</html>
```